In Qt, the style sheet set for the child window does not take effect normally
I'm developing a program using Qt/C++ in Windows.
I had created two subclasses that inherit from QWidge. The windows based on these two classes were created respectively, one of which is a child window of the other. Subsequently, I placed a QLabel in the child window.
Surprisingly, the child window background was transparent.
When I set a style sheet for the parent window, the style sheet works normally. But when I set a style sheet for the sub-window, the style sheet does not work on the sub-window itself, but on the label inside it.
Just like this: the stylesheet for the sub-window doesn't work well. (The blue area in the picture was not the sub-window. The sub-window was larger than the blue area, but was invisible because it was transparent.)
Here is widget.h
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>

class InnerWidget : public QWidget{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   InnerWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
   ~InnerWidget();

   QLabel *label = new QLabel("good",this);

};




class MainWidget : public QWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   MainWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
   ~MainWidget();

   InnerWidget *innerWidget = new InnerWidget(this);
};


Here is widget.cpp
#include "widget.h"

MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget *parent)
   : QWidget(parent)
{
   setFixedSize(500,500);
   setStyleSheet("background-color:red;");

}

MainWidget::~MainWidget()
{
}


InnerWidget::InnerWidget(QWidget *parent)
   :QWidget(parent)
{
   setFixedSize(200,300);
   move(100,100);

   setStyleSheet("background-color:blue;");
   label->setFixedSize(50,50);
}

InnerWidget::~InnerWidget()
{

}

And here is the main.cpp
#include "widget.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   MainWidget w;
   w.show();
   return a.exec();
}

Currently I don't know what causes it.

Aren't Qt stylesheets somewhat deprecated? In any case; they never really worked properly for me - I'd advice avoiding them and just style your widgets with code.

What causeed the sub-window to become transparent?

@JesperJuhl While I agree that, generally speaking, Qt stylesheets are not very well implemented, the one (and possibly 'only') benefit they do have is that they allow a user to supply their own palette/theme via an 'application wide' stylesheet.  So if they can be made to work in a particular case it's often the most convenient route.  So I wouldn't necessarily avoid using them.

Note that your code appears to work as intended (for me at least) if you remove the Q_OBJECT macro from the InnerWidget class definition.  That suggests to me that your InnerWidget type is not being recognized as a subclass of QWidget by the Qt stylesheet implementation.  I'm not very familiar with these particular aspects of Qt so I'll let others comment.

Direct QWidget subclasses never draw anything set by the stylesheet, it's specifically explained in the QSS reference related to QWidget styling. Either override paintEvent() and use QStyle primitives, or at least set the Qt::WA_StyledBackground attribute. The only case in which the background works for direct QWidget subclasses is when they're top level widgets (aka, windows), because the background is required for all widgets eventually added as children.

@G.M.  thank you for your reply. When I deleted Q_OBJECT, my program interface did appear as I expected, but what is the principle?

@JesperJuhl They're actually quite alive and still supported. Their problem is that, due to their nature, their implementation isn't always consistent with underlying QStyles (which are considered as fall backs and therefore not reliable when used along with QSS). In reality, as long as the QStyle behavior is properly understood (both on the QApp developer and the QStyle sides) they are consistent, once their behavior is understood. In any case, for simple case scenarios like this, they always work as expected, assuming the docs are properly followed (which is the problem of the OP).

@G.M. That's curious. I really know almost nothing about C++, but it would be interesting to know why using that macro changes the QSS behavior. In Python bindings (for which that macro isn't used) that is irrelevant, and they normally follow the known pattern: only use the QSS for top level windows, not for QWidget subclasses unless they override paintEvent() or the related WA_StyledBackground is used. Maybe it's worth a question on its own?
